# Android proguard InflateException

Tags: android, android-proguard

In my app I use a custom image view from exetrnal `jar` library. And if I enable proguard, I get exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.example.testapp/eu.example.testapp.ui.activities.DetailsActivity_}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fr.idapps.image.IDAppsImageView
```

in the `proguard-android.txt` I tried to put:

```
-keep class fr.idapps.** { *; }

-keep class fr.idapps.image.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.widget.ImageView

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}
```

but nothing helps. I also tried to move this class from the library to my code. Even in this case I got the same error.

Here is the place where this class is inflated:

```
<eu.example.testapp.ui.views.LocationItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/item_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium" >

    <!-- Header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/light_anthracite"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium" >

           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_location_item_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_detail_location" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/view_location_item_title"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/view_detail_item_title_location"
               android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fr.idapps.image.IDAppsImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_location_item_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
        app:imageRatio="preserve" />

</eu.example.testapp.ui.views.LocationItem>
```

EDIT: I use the last gradle version and enable proguard in this way:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true // enables/disables proguard
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    outputFileName = "Test-v${variant.versionName}-v${variant.versionCode}.apk"
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to add your custom class (which having in your package) into `proguard-project.txt` :-

```
-keep public class com.abc.xyz
```

and unable to see that your not include `eu.example.testapp.ui.views.LocationItem`

Comment: what do you mean under "custom package"?

Comment: I tried. I created `CustomImageView` and copied there the code from `IDAppsImageView`, then added to the proguard `-keep class eu.example.testapp.ui.views.image.CustomImageView` and it gave me the same exception

Comment: what is ur gradle version or will u show ur gradle file

Comment: added to the question